# Confusion regarding worst case robust optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, supremum-and-infimum, operations-research

In a book, for an uncertain matrix $A(o)=A_0+o \cdot A_1$; where $o \in R$ is an uncertain scalar between a compact interval, then
$\max_{-c\leq o \leq c} ||A(o)x-b||$

is re-written as maximum of,

$\{||(A_0-o.A_1)x||,||(A_0+o.A_1)x||\}$

Answer (score 2):

> **Fact.** A convex function on an interval attains its maximum at an extremity of the interval.

This is easy to proof, but to save space an focus on real issues, here is a like to a simple proof https://qr.ae/pNrZo6.

Now, for any $x \in \mathbb R^n$, the given function is convex on the interval $[-c, c]$ , and so in view of my introductory comment, you have $\max_{o \in [-c,c]}f(o) = \max(f(-c),f(c))$. Conclude.

Comment: The edit "$1$" ==> "$c$" makes sense. The rest of the edit is detrimental as you've removed the defintiion of the object "$f$" completely, and it's no longer clear what my answer is talking about...